# Restrict #include to only search the current directory

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

`#include` by convention uses quotes versus angle brackets to indicate whether the preprocessor should search the current directory before the system header directories.

Suppose you want to search *only* the current directory, and stop with an error if the file is not found there. Is it valid to do that with a path rather than just a file name? Such as

```
#include "./foo.h"
```

Comment: Doesn't work the way you want with either clang or gcc in a test I did here; do you have a specific compiler you're trying?

Comment: @CarlNorum No. I would ideally like it if the standard specified a way to only look in the current directory; failing that, I would settle for something that works with clang, GCC and MSVC.

Comment: There's definitely not a standard-specified way. Pretty much everything about `#include` behaviour is implementation-defined.

Comment: I'd find it pretty odd for something like this to work for clang, GCC and MSVC.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Not that I mind whether it's by my proposed method or otherwise, but I am mildly surprised that there is *no* even de facto portable way to tell the preprocessor to look only in a particular directory.

Comment: If you make a directory containing garbage/compilation killing headers with the same names as the ones you're trying to restrict, and make sure it's the first `-I` flag on your command line, that will probably behave the way you want. It's pretty gross, though.

Comment: These features were largely invented back when personal responsibility was still a thing ;) You're supposed to sort out the directories yourself. Ofc now we can have CMake do some verification for us but it's still not really a feature designed for foolproofness. If that makes any sense.

Comment: Your assumption that `./something.h` should work is flawed since `/a/b/./c` is the same as `/a/b/c`.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli "./" in this context meaning "relative to me" not "relative to whatever other path you're currently checking" is not too wild an expectation IMO. I think it's a natural expectation. It's how relative path expansion works in pretty much any other context. Even though technically yes both are valid

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings it *is* a pretty wild expectation IMHO. The compiler merely concatenates paths to search for the file. The default include paths will be checked and the concatenation will happen, making the leading dot useless. That's the reason why you can `#include "sys/mman.h"` for example.

Comment: I think ISO C could work on systems where there is no directory structure at all, so this is necessarily implementation-defined. However, using quotes instead of brackets should do the fine `#include "foo.h"`.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli That is, at best, a circular argument. The fact that "the compiler merely concatenates paths to search for the file" is _how it does what it actually does_, not _what one might intuitively expect it to do_. I'm completely aware of what it _does_ do, we're talking about whether the OP's expectation that it might do something different is reasonable. I think that it very much is. But we can agree to disagree.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I get your point, one might expect it to not look in other dirs if you say `./`. Makes sense.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Yep. I am actually a little surprised to discover it works this way, even though your rundown of the technical reasons of how that works are perfectly understandable and normal. If I were writing the implementation I'd probably have made leading `./` or `../` "anchor" the relative path to that of the current document. Maybe they had reasons not to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard `#include` syntax does not support what you're asking for.

You can however work around the issue in two ways:

1. If you only need to include files in the current directory, then the GCC flag `-nostdinc` will suffice. It suppresses standard include paths and leaves you with only the current directory.

   ```
   $ echo 'int func(void) {return 1;}' > foo.h
   $ echo '#include "foo.h"' | gcc -E -              # success
   $ echo '#include "foo.h"' | gcc -nostdinc -E -    # success
   $ echo '#include "stdio.h"' | gcc -E -            # success
   $ echo '#include "stdio.h"' | gcc -nostdinc -E -  # failure
   ```
2. If you also want to be able to include other files, you can use a command line define to specify the absolute path of the current directory and use it to include files that are strictly in the current directory by using their full path. This will still let you use the normal include syntax for other libraries and is also pretty easy to integrate in a Makefile.

   File to import *strictly* from current directory (`foo.h`):

   ```
   int func(void) {return 1;}
   ```

   File where you want to perform the import (`test.c`):

   ```
   #define XSTR(x) #x
   #define STR(x) XSTR(x)
   #define ABSOLUTE_PATH(lib) STR(CUR_DIR_PATH/lib)

   #include ABSOLUTE_PATH(foo.h)
   ```

   Command line:

   ```
   $ gcc -DCUR_DIR_PATH=$(pwd) -E test.c
   ```

   Adding `#include ABSOLUTE_PATH(stdio.h)` to `test.c` will make the above fail as intended:

   ```
   $ echo '#include ABSOLUTE_PATH(stdio.h)' >> test.c
   $ gcc -DCUR_DIR_PATH=$(pwd) -E test.c
   test.c:7:33: fatal error: /home/marco/stdio.h: No such file or directory
   ```

   Tested with GCC and Clang and it works fine.

Comment: Good answer - but it should note that both suggested solutions are [arguably] not the best way to go about this. One relies on a single compiler's flag, and the other violates your code with a massive abstraction leak. The correct approach is to organise your codebase differently, making it so that whatever problem OP is having (which wasn't ever actually stated) simply doesn't exist in the first place, possibly by using better header file names.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings *"arguably not the best way to go about this"* - they are the *only* way to go about this. You should've probably directed this comment to OP or included it in your answer. I surely agree that this is an XY problem and the real solution is organizing the project in a decent way, but that's not what OP asked.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings also, there's literally nothing wrong on relying on compiler flags or command line defines. Any decently sized project does so, and it can be very easily integrated in a Makefile to make it transparent (also another thing that any decently sized project does). The fact that it might be considered good or not is entirely subjective.

Comment: Of course it's subjective . No, the comment belongs on this answer, because it's about the answer. There are other ways to go about this and I named one of them. A good answer at least hangs up a sign about that :)

Answer (score 2):

This is going to depend on the compiler, since the standard calls it [implementation-defined](http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.include#3).

Interestingly, [the GCC docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html) also don't talk about this either way but, despite common sense suggesting that your hypothesis is valid, experimentation with GCC 4.8.5 suggests otherwise:

```
$ mkdir test
$ touch test/inc.h
$ echo '#include "./inc.h"' > test.cpp
$ g++ test.cpp -Itest -c
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada,go,lto --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --disable-libgcj --with-isl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.5-20150702/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/isl-install --with-cloog=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.5-20150702/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/cloog-install --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=x86-64 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39) (GCC)
```

Comment: @CarlNorum There. Turns out the answer is the opposite :)

Comment: That's what I thought ;-)

Comment: In my defence, it's 3am :D

Comment: Just noticed I also linked to the C++ spec on a C question